# Connect with SSH: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I've set up a user with a home directory like this:

```
|- .ssh/
|-- authorized_keys
```

I've added the private key to my local bash, and the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine.

I know the keys work, because I tried to add the public key to the another users `authorized_keys` file, and it logged me in. It is just when I try with the user I just made that it doesn't work.

The `.ssh/` have permissions `700`, and the `authorized_keys` have permissions `600`, and both are owned by the user I created.

When I run `ssh [myuser]@[thedomain] -v`, it tells me in the 2 last lines:

```
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

However, on the other user I can log right in, so it can find the key on my machine.

It is like it can't find the public key on the remote machine.
The remote machine is running Ubuntu.

This is from `/etc/passwd`:

`[myuser]:x:1001:1002:,,,:/home/[myuser]:/bin/bash`

This is from `/var/log/auth.log`:

`Aug 26 14:11:17 fra sshd[32172]: Connection closed by <my ip address> [preauth]`

EDIT: I tried to create a different user with a different user name, and it worked. Are there any reserved user names?

Comment: What does the `/var/log/auth.log` tell on the server side?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I added it to the post.

Comment: Check if there are differences in those two users (you can update your post with /etc/password from user that can connect). Other than that, check sshd_config and see if you have allowed access to selected users with AllowUsers option

Comment: Well, I deleted the user. I know the `AllowUsers` option wasn't specified, so everyone should have had permission to connect with ssh.

Comment: The permissions of the home directory of your user?

Comment: The permissions were all set to my user, so that shouldn't have been the problem.